# macOS Sierra / Numbers 4.0: Problem with saving on a Synology via AFP

Tags: numbers, afp, macos

I updated my Mac to 10.12 Sierra and updated Pages, Numbers and Keynote afterwards to the latest versions.

So far so good, everything running normal.

But unfortunately saving a Numbers file via AFP on a local Synology NAS (DS1815+, latest DSM) caused the application to crash and kicked all connections to shared folders.

Saving on the local HDD is no problem at all.

Then I tried to figure out whether thats a single problem with AFP and killed the AFP file service on the NAS to only start the SMB2 service.

No problem to save on the NAS via SMB.

I tried to save a numbers document on the NAS via AFP from another Mac. This time with an older version of numbers (3.6.2) but on a freshly updated macOS Sierra and it causes the same crash of numbers and all connections to the NAS.

**Therefore:**
It seems to be a problem with macOS Sierra and the AFP server of the current Synology DSM (6.0.2-8451 Update 1).

---

Is anyone experiencing the same issues?
Does anyone have a suggestion for a workaround?

Thanks a lot.

---

Edit:

I think it might be a problem with the versioning of the applications which use [file versioning](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203598). Someone [described the same behavior with Preview](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7675631?start=15&tstart=0) while saving a JPG image. And I could reproduce the same crash with my Macs.

Comment: I am questioning whether this a general Sierra/AFP issue or just in combination with Synology Disk Stations.

Comment: Same thing here. I switched to SMB for the Syno for that reason.

Comment: I would do that too .. but I will get problems with [mangled names](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209876/el-capitan-strange-folder-names-on-synology-nas) than..

Comment: have you tried that?
https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=106129

Comment: Thx! Didn't do it for now because I am afraid of corrupted file/folder paths afterwards. Especially with alle the Adobe InDesign file links & others. I have to read more about the mangled name topic....

Comment: I didn't have to do that anyways. Worked just like it should out of the box...
I just enabled SMB3. This seems to work as well.

Comment: Okay. Let me test the SMB3 setting. I will give feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I tried SMB3 settings, but of course it still mangles the names. I tried around a little bit and will read more about SMB/CIFS and AFP and how to change from AFP to SMB, so what to think about when changing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread while looking for a resolution to a problem with my ReadyNAS device.  The root cause appears to be that Apple removed the AFP protocol from macOS Sierra, at least according to comments on Apple's discussion boards.  SMB still works, but AFP has either been removed, or at least deprecated.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/30684682

Comment: Apple started with Mavericks:
SMB2 is the new default protocol for sharing files in OS X Mavericks. SMB2 is superfast, increases security, and improves Windows compatibility.

Comment: My Time Machine backup is running perfectly on the NAS via AFP. No problem with that.